# Is it possible to switch from native swiftUI to flutter for IOS development after publishing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I created and published an app on the apple app store, using Xcode/SwiftUI. Now that it is published, I will be focusing on the android version using flutter/react. Since flutter/react supports both IOS and android, it would make sense to release versions on both platforms using flutter/react instead of using Xcode/SwiftUI for IOS and flutter/react for Android.

Will it be possible to release IOS versions of the App using flutter/react instead of Xcode's SwiftUI if the app is already published using Xcode/SwiftUI? Essentially I want to deprecate all of my SwiftUI code and release future versions using flutter/react only.

I am very new to flutter, so apologies if this is a dumb question

Comment: Yes you just keep the bundle id the same

Comment: You can release the first version with swift, the next with objective-c, then ionic, then flutter, then react native, Apple does not care.